# i get error when i try to run query in access through C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

i have this query:

```
SELECT DO3Tbl.CodeDip, DO3Tbl.BarcodeD, Sum(DO3Tbl.Qty) AS Qty,
       Max(DO3Tbl.Mly) AS Mly, [Qty]-[Mly] AS Tot, ABS(Tot) AS TotAbs
```

when i run this query in access its work's excellent

but when i run this query in C# code like this:

```
SQL =     SELECT DO3Tbl.CodeDip, DO3Tbl.BarcodeD, Sum(DO3Tbl.Qty) AS Qty,
          Max(DO3Tbl.Mly) AS Mly, [Qty]-[Mly] AS Tot, ABS(Tot) AS TotAbs 
Cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Cmd.Dispose();
```

i get this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression '[Qty]-[Mly]' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: You could try putting a `MIN()` around `[Qty]-[Mly]`, and see if it accepts it then?

Comment: That isn't valid C#. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not valid C# alright, but apparently it executes, and the error seems to be with the SQL (it doesn't recognise `Qty` and `Mly` as not requiring an aggregate function), not with the C# part.

Comment: It's not valid SQL either -- for this to work, it would have to have a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot wrong with the query as far as Access is concerned, for example, you are not selecting from any table, also, you cannot use an Alias that is the sames as a field name. How about:

```
SELECT DO3Tbl.CodeDip, DO3Tbl.BarcodeD, Sum(DO3Tbl.Qty) AS SumOfQty, Max(DO3Tbl.Mly) AS MaxOfMly, Sum([Qty]-[Mly]) AS Tot, Abs(Tot) AS TotAbs
FROM DO3Tbl
GROUP BY DO3Tbl.CodeDip, DO3Tbl.BarcodeD;
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose that  instead of counting  the

> Tot 
>   and 
>   TotAbs

values directly in the query.

It's better to count them in the code since we are able to avoid any issue related to the query execution order in the SELECT clause.

Hence your query would be like that:

```
SELECT DO3Tbl.CodeDip, DO3Tbl.BarcodeD, Sum(DO3Tbl.Qty) AS Qty,
       Max(DO3Tbl.Mly) AS Mly
```

Cheers.